# DocuSign - .Net Core - JWT user token error consent_required

Tags: docusignapi

I get the following error using the token authentication.

```
ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Completed with response Body: {"error":"consent_required"}
```

And I used an admin user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain consent for your user for the app. Even if you're an admin.
Consent means you allow this third part integration to access information using the API and it must be given at least once.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-individual-consent/ has detailed instructions but I wonder if you downloaded code from GitHub (or quickstart) and tried to use JWT without using Auth Code Grant.
If you use Auth Code Grant for the same IK first - you will be asked for consent and thereafter you can use JWT without issues.

Comment: I just followed the steps you provided after getting a sample solution from the quickstart. By default it use the Code Grant, that one works fine but the JWT is still giving the same error

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: if the Auth Code Grant workflow succeeds but JWT does not, you haven't granted the `impersonation` scope during the Consent process

Comment: [https://ibb.co/PrYNCcn](https://ibb.co/PrYNCcn) the `impersonation` wasn't in the consent process

Comment: you can add it manually, we'll update this code soon.

Comment: open any browser to this URL (remember to update your CLIENT_ID first) - https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code &scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=CLIENT_ID &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fds%2Fcallback

Comment: do you mind marking this question as answered? thanks!